# NFC intent calling onPause before onNewIntent - How to know the origin of the onPause call?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, android-lifecycle, foreground

While scanning an NFC tag in an application with Foreground Dispatch enabled, `onPause()` is called before `onNewIntent()`. Is it possible to get the NFC intent already in `onPause()` so that I can stop (or not) processes according to the origin of the intent?

Since the activity is in the foreground and should not be paused/resumed when a tag is scanned, and since I have tasks that have to stop or start in `onPause`/`onResume`, you can see the problem.

The `getIntent().getAction()` is always "MAIN", but surely there must be a way to get a more accurate description of the intent? Or is not possible to know it's an NFC intent before entering `onNewIntent()`?

Comment: paste your intent filters. 
I guess some problem in your intent filters.

Comment: It's not a problem with the IntentFilter. The IntentFilter of the NFC is only read in the onNewIntent() method and doesn't exist in the onPause() yet. What I need is to be able to detect whether the onPause() was called by the system or the user.

Comment: On Tap NFC onPause should not be called ..
Are you sure your NFC events getting generated ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you won't be able to know what the new intent is before it is delivered to your activity in `onNewIntent()`. That's the point of the `onNewIntent()` callback: Deliver the information about the new intent to your activity. Only when this method is called, you can obtain the new intent through the `intent` parameter of that method:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    ...
}
```

Note that `getIntent()` will always return the intent that initially started your activity unless you explicitly update that intent using `setIntent(newintent)`. So if you started the activity through the launcher you will get the intent action MAIN.

`onPause`/`onResume()` is called due to the way the NFC service dispatches the intent to your activity. There is nothing you can do about that. In fact that should not be something that you need to differentiate in your application logic. If `onPause` is called you should do whatever you would normally do in there regardless of whether this was invoked due to explicit user UI interaction moving some other UI component in front of yours or due to the system moving some (invisible) UI component in front of yours. If your current `onPause` logic really needs to differentiate between the two, then it might probably better be done in `onStop`.

Comment: I used onStart/onStop instead when I noticed that they are not called when a tag is scanned. Your answer joins my solution so I'll validate it.